# Page load request while processing Ajax request crashes browser

Tags: c#, ajax, google-chrome, asp.net-mvc-5

I have chrome giving me the "Aw Snap" error if I do a subsequent (standard) request while my previous Ajax request is still processing.  In my browser debugger I can see that the Ajax request has a status of (Cancelled).  Can anyone explain this behaviour or help me to get around this?

The code which causes this problem is proprietary although I think the concept is fairly simple and I was hoping someone can shed any light given the description.

I have a method within a controller called GetItemCount

```
[NoCache]
public JsonResult GetItemCount(...)
{
    // other code removed for brevity
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    // other code removed for brevity
    return new JsonResult 
    {
        Data = new { count = 10 },
        JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
        ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8
    }
}
```

The above method gets called via Jquery Ajax library using

```
$.ajax(request);
```

Now, while that indicator badge is waiting to be shown, if I click on an *href* tag anywhere on the page...the tab crashes.  If I wait for the indicator to show and then click, its all okay. I have also attached the Chrome debugger which marks the request as (Cancelled).

[image]

Some more debugging information, the below is what the Chrome developer tools tells me

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of
>   its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help,
>   check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/. browserLink:37 Setting
>   'XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials' for synchronous requests is
>   deprecated.

Comment: Could you make a new page which replicates the issue without the proprietary code and post it here?

Comment: Added as much info as possible.  Hope that's sufficient.